# Does Sitecore 9.1 support WFFM?

Tags: wffm, upgrade

We have Sitecore 8.2 with WFFM forms, can we use the same forms with Sitecore 9.1 when we upgrade?

Comment: That functionality has been replaced with Sitecore Forms and WFFM is not compatible with it.

Answer (score 16):

No, it does not.

Also see here: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers.aspx

It states:

> Note! Web Forms For Marketers was deprecated with the release of Sitecore XP 9.1

9.0.2 is the last release where WFFM can be used.

Answer (score 4):

No.

> Note! Web Forms For Marketers was deprecated with the release of Sitecore XP 9.1

Source: [Web Forms For Marketers](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web_Forms_For_Marketers.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re create in Sitecore 9.x. Some of the WFFM supported controls like FileUpload, captcha etc., are not available. You need add some Forms extension available in Github.